# How to customised react-navigation instead of react-native-navigation in jhipster?

Tags: react-native, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I am developing a react native app using jhipster tool which inbuilt provides react-native navigation. Instead of react-native navigation, I want to use a react-navigation library is there any way to customize?